# Подключить gradle-проект-библиотеку к проекту в Eclipse.

Tags: android, github, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

Доброго времени суток!

**Дано**: Android-приложение (далее приложение) в виде проекта в Eclipse; проект-библиотека (далее библиотека) на gitHabe, собранная (как я понял) в Android Studio с помощью gradle.

**Цель**: подключить библиотеку к проекту. Использовать её возможности для реализации анимированного поведения "homeButton" в ActionBare, как рекомендует гугл в "material menu". Гифка с результатом есть в README на gitHabe.

**Проблема**: способы подключения библиотек, мне известные, в данном случае не работают (добавление библиотеки в workspace (с копированием на диск), отметка её как isLibrary, подключение к приложению как библиотеки не позволяет приложению видеть её классы). Умею подключать библиотеки гугла (adMob, appCompat), сторонние (HtmlCleaner, pullToRefresh). Тут, похоже, надо как-то по другому, используя Gradle.

**Возможное решение**: после долгой ночи безуспешных попыток пришёл к выводу, что можно просто вручную выдернуть все *.java файлы, вручную же поправить им imports и package, добавить включённые в проект* .xml (drawable, style, strings, etc). Это ведь сработает, правда же?

**Желаемое решение**:

1. Объяснение/ мануал (на русском желательно)/ направление гугления для автоматического подключения библиотеки к приложению.
2. Eclipse альтернативы сей библиотеки в виде ссылки.

**Подробности**: приложение имеет minSdk=9, targetSdk=21; подключена appCompat-v7-21, пользую ActionBarActivity c ActionBarCompat, не ToolBar.

**Ссылки на gitHub**: [приложение](https://github.com/mohaxspb/Odnako), [библиотека](https://github.com/balysv/material-menu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге подобный случай решаем (вряд ли правильно, но работает же!) ручным копированием файлов классов, изменением их **package** и импортом **R** класса своего проекта.

Далее надо так же в ручном режиме скопировать всё из **values**, включая **атрибуты** (//res/values/attr) и **стили** (res/values/style). И остальные ресурсы. **Drawable**, **strings**, например.

Так мы можем всё это скомпилировать и пользовать. Ну или на **AndroidStudio** переходить. Но искать лёгкие пути - это не **путь воина**.