# Сборка jar библиотеки appcompat

Tags: android, aide

Такая ситуация, мне нужно собрать и подключить jar библиотеку appcompat. В силу определённых обстоятельств я не могу использовать sdk. Остаётся подключать как jar. Но проблема в том, что jar файл appcompat из репозитория гугл не содержит ресурсов. Они находятся рядом с ним в папке. Как мне можно собрать и подключить appcompat с ресурсами?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте скопировать все строки, картинки, аттрибуты, стили и другое содержимое ресурсов appcompat в папку своего проекта.

Это долго и нудно, но другие библиотеки я так [поключал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/372381/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-gradle-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-eclipse)

---

Либо создайте папку-проект с ресурсами и подключите его как библиотеку к вашему проекту.

Comment: Как создать проект с ресурсами?

Comment: Ну, в смысле создайте проект из как обычно и поместите туда папку с ресурсами.

Comment: Я не хочу путать свои ресурсы с ресурсами библиотеки

Comment: Можно как то их в отдельную папку

Comment: Ну так я же так и написал - создайте новый проект, поместите туда ресурсы и подключите его как библиотеку к основному проекту. И поясните что вам мешает пользовать SDK

Comment: Я использую AIDE на планшете, и хотя там есть возможность добавлять зависимости, у меня не получается(возможно из за взломаной версии)

Comment: Есть ли там возможность создания проектов из существующего кода?

Comment: Насколько я понял в проекте - библиотеки не нужно MainActivity, его можно удалить и поправить Manifest от ссылок на activity?

Comment: По идее всё верно, можно удалять активити

Comment: aart:aart exited with code 11. Выбивает при добавлении проекта Что это может быть.

Comment: Всё что угодно)

Comment: Может я не правильно подключил проект. Я взял только папку app(src, build, build.gradle).

Comment: Папку res тоже добавьте

Comment: Внутри src, res java и manifest

Comment: У меня больше нет идей(